# Angular pane splitter where one of the pane having form throwing form validation error

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, forms, validation

I trying to split the pane in angular js , where in one of the pane having form with validation. I have assigned the form with the name.In the controller i am having the method for the form validation.But it is throwing error as 'Cannot read property '$invalid' of undefined'. This is the link i have provided the example. how can i make the pane splitter having form validation work.

```
function canUpdate() {
          // Can't update if form fields are bad.
          if ($scope.myForm.$invalid) {
            return false;
          }

          return true;
        }
```

[plunkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/LB75lqDPuAwyxhPV7Ptu?p=preview)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A scope cannot see the properties of its children scopes (more generally: descendant scopes); in this case the controller is set in a *parent* element of the form, thus the scope of the form is a child of the controller. That is why `$scope.myForm` is undefined in the controller.

The solution is to define a controller at the form element:

```
<form name="myForm" class="form-horizontal" ng-controller="myOtherController">
```

In many cases you can even move the logic of the enclosing controller in the inner controller. This is reasonable, as the logic about the form should be placed near the form and not above it. Better yet, encapsulate the functionality in a directive.

If the logic must remain in the enclosing controller, then they have to communicate somehow; many questions in Stack Overflow have addressed the controller communications issue, you can use a shared service if you do not have any more specific needs.